# Where to run parameter validation

Tags: structure, theory, single-responsibility-principle, responsibility

Lets say we have a function, and a caller to that function

```
function baz(){
    myVar = null;
    foo(myVar);
}

function foo(bar){
    //do stuff
}
```

where should validation on the parameters happen?

It could be

```
function baz(){
    myVar = null;
    if(myVar != null){
        foo(myVar);
    }
}
```

or it could be

```
function foo(bar){
    if(myVar == null) return null;

    //do stuff
}
```

What is better? Or if it's situational, when should I use what?

Perhaps an extension of this would also be when should I do

```
myVar['key'] = myFunc();
function myFunc(){
   return x;
}
```

vs

```
myFunc();
function myFunc(myVar){
    myVar['key'] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends. If you are implementing for speed, you may want to consider leavin the choice of validation to the user. If you are implementing for stability, you may want to validate as part of the function.

Imagine an array and the push() function validates. Now imagine using that function a a few hundred times per frame at 60 FPS in a game. That's an extra >6000 if calls per second. Thats a big enough number to matter.

Comment: In the situation of making a flexible base class, what would you recommend?  I want it to be able to handle pretty much anything (provided I follow proper implementation on the child classes

Comment: Perhaps in this case you could use #ifdefs to determine if they want automatic validation or not. Of course you can only do that on compiled languages. You might be able to hack something up in interpreted languages. To be honest though if your use is never going to be similar to my example case of a game, just validate in the function.